# Unable to call AppSync GraphQL api from Lambda: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to call my AWS AppSync graphQL API from Lambda, but I'm stuck at an error that I can't solve, so I'd like to ask your help to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The credentials seems correct and the query should be correct (see below).

The lambda function is deployed using the Serverless framework and I can invoke it with `sls invoke --function <my_function_name>`.

I have been following [this article](https://janhesters.com/how-to-use-aws-appsync-in-lambda-functions/)

**The error I'm getting is:**

```
{
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
"errorMessage": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null",
"trace": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null",
    "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:310:20)",
    "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)",
    "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
]
}

Error --------------------------------------------------

Error: Invoked function failed
  at AwsInvoke.log (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invoke/index.js:101:31)
  at AwsInvoke.tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
  at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
  at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
  at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
  at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
  at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
  at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
```

**Here is my Lambda function in full:**

```
'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;
require('isomorphic-fetch');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

module.exports.pushNotificationHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const appsyncClient = new AWSAppSyncClient({
        url: process.env.GRAPHQL_API_ID,
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
        auth: {
            type: 'AWS_IAM',
            credentials: AWS.config.credentials
        },
        disableOffline: true
    },
        {
            defaultOptions: {
                query: {
                    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
                    errorPolicy: 'all',
                },
            },
        }
    );

    const client = await appsyncClient.hydrated();

    try {

        const result = await client.query({
            query: gql`
                query GetUser {
                    getUser(id: "<A_VALID_USER_ID") {
                        firstname
                    }
                }
            `,
            variables: {}
        });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        return error;
    }

    callback(null, event);

};
```

**Credentials**

I have checked the credentials by simply logging and checked in `CloudWatch`. There is both an access key and a session token, so I would assume my credentials are correct.

**Query**

The query I have checked by executing it from the AppSync console. It should work.

**IAM Permissions**

The permissions are set in the Serverless configuration file, but is the same as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appsync:GraphQL"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:<REGION>:<ACCOUNTID>:apis/<APIID>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

This error typically happens when inputs are incorrect or appSyncClient is not instantiated properly. Make sure that

- `GRAPHQL_API_ID` `AWS_REGION` has a legit graphQL endpoint
- `credentials` exists

Also, I recommend you to go to AppSync UI console and request the same Query and see if it returns the result. If it does, then it's an issue related to the initialization of appSyncClient

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking to only using `return` and not `callback`. Using an `async` function means you do not need to use callbacks and that's probably what is affecting the response of your Lambda function.